# Quagga BGP - How do I remove a blackhole from Quagga BGP configuration

Tags: linux, networking, bgp, quagga

[image: Blackhole]

In the above screenshot you can see that the preferred route for 10.120.15.0/24 is into a 0.0.0.0 black hole.

First, how do I remove that black hole from `vtysh`

Second how do I add a new IP in there with a high weighting to replace the old blackhole?